# how to make colored border around centered images

Tags: html, css

I basically have a stack of images that are wrapped in a div that centers the entire stack. I would like to create a thick border or padding around the entire stack, not the individual images but i dont know how to do this with css. any help would be great. Each image is also in its own div for other styling purposes. Also, adding style attributes to the individual images is not acceptable because the images are actually displayed using angularjs ng-repeat directive. below is just pseudocode for what is essentially happening but i am looking for a way to border the entire stack of images.

```
<div class="center">
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the HTML correctly formatted? you don't close out your </div tags with the corresponding >

Comment: `.center { border: 1px solid red; }` ?

Comment: Could you please add working JSFiddle, or even some picture of what you expect? Is not clear

Comment: yeah thats just a typo in the post. real html is fine. the images do not take up the full width of the outer div so bordering the outer div does not work. I just want a border around the stack of images that are centered within that outer div

Comment: okay can you point me in the right direction for accomplishing that @Paulie_D?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/gpJxma):

This generates a border around your outer div:

```
.center {
    border: 5px solid #D32232;
}
```

I used a **solid** line. You can also use other lines. These are the possibilities:

- dotted
- dashed
- double
- groove
- ridge
- inset
- outset

Check out this page for the full documentation on [border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

Comment: Yes thank you sorry it is a little bit hard to specify exactly what i want. the problem is that the images do not take up the full width of the div so bordering just the outer div does not solve the problem

Comment: @NateHolmes Can you maybe make a drawing of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

you could border your outer div with a black outline

```
  .center{ border: 5px solid #000;}
```

and then your inner divs with a color

```
   .center div{border: 4px dashed blue;}
```

if you wanted to outline each img if there was more than one in a div you could do something like this

```
  .center div img{border: 3px dotted red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need another wrapper shrink-wrapped around the images to do that. Otherwise, this is not possble.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper div img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```